# Why are my files smaller after I FTP them using this Python program?

Tags: python-2.7, ftp

I'm trying to send some files (a zip and a Word doc) to a directory on a server using ftplib. I have the broad strokes sorted out:

```
session = ftplib.FTP(ftp.server, 'user','pass')    
filewpt = open(file, mode)    
readfile = open(file, mode)
session.cwd(new/work/directory)    
session.storbinary('STOR filename.zip', filewpt)    
session.storbinary('STOR readme.doc', readfile)    
print "filename.zip and readme.doc were sent to the folder on ftp"   
readfile.close()   
filewpt.close()    
session.quit()
```

This may provide someone else what they are after but not me. I have been using FileZilla as a check to make sure the files were transferred. When I see they have made it to the server, I see that they are both way smaller or even zero K for the readme.doc file. Now I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I stored the file in 'binary transfer mode' <--- whatever that means.

This is where my problems lie. I have no idea at all (yet) what is meant by binary transfer mode. Is it simply that I have to use `retrbinary` to return the files to their original state?

Could someone please explain to me like I'm a two year old what has happened to my files? If there's any more info required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fantastic resource. Solved most of my problems. Still trying to work out the intricacies of FTPs, but I guess I will save that for another day. The link below builds a function to effortlessly upload files to an FTP without the partial upload problem that I've seen experienced by more than one Stack Exchanger.

http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm